# How do I prove $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ using the induction method?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

I am having difficulties in solving the expression $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1} =\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, using the induction method. How is the inductive step taken in this case?

Comment: This should be as straightforward as an induction proof can be.  What is the obstacle?  Add $x^n$ to both sides.  What happens to the right-hand side?

Comment: The obstacle is how to take the inductive step.
The induction base is taken properly:
For $n=1$, $1=\frac{1-x^1}{1-x}=1$

The problem is how to take the next step, how to prove for $n+1$.

Comment: This question has been answered here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502997/induction-proof-dealing-with-geometric-series

Comment: @felipeduda Read my entire comment.  Answer the question embedded therein.  You have the answer that Ennar posted, which you stated you understood.

Comment: I did! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the formula holds for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Then

$$\underbrace{1+x+\ldots + x^{n-1}}_{\text{formula holds for this part}}+x^n = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} + x^n.$$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $1+x + \dots + x^{n-1} = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$.

Then

$$1+x+ \dots + x^{n} = (1+ x + \dots + x^{n-1}) + x^n = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} + x^n$$
$$= \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} + \frac{x^n(1-x)}{1-x} = \frac{1-x^n + x^n - x^{n+1}}{1-x}= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$